# .htaccess is restricting access to root level pages. How do I stop this?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several webpages on my root directory (e.g. index.htm, home.php and home_page.php) which all are starting points for different versions of my website.

I ahve upgraded PHP version (as advised by my hosting service) from 5.3 to 5.6.  This has put a .htaccess file on my site and now my PHP pages on root won't load and I get a "500 Internal Server Error" message.

The .htaccess file was created by the web hosting provider when the PHP version was updated.

The content of the .htaccess file is AddType application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5.

If I delete the .htaccess file then my pages work OK as before but I do not know what the implications of deleteing this file are.

How do I log my exception errors?

Any help on how I can getall of my pages to be displayed, please?

Comment: Did you try dealeting the htaccess file?

Comment: 500 is a general error code which could come from a problematic .htaccess. We need to see the .htaccess file to help you.

Comment: Try to log your exceptions for more detailed diagnosis

Comment: An upgrade of the php will _not_ create a distributed configuration file ("htaccess").